# Run Time Error '438' for copying data between two workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

the following code is to open two workbooks, source/target, find last row of target, copy range of source, and paste into last row of target, but I am getting **Run Time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method**. The error is at:  *'sBook_t.Sheets("Data Dump").Range("B" & lRow2).Paste'*

here is the code:

```
Sub last_row()

Dim sBook_t As Workbook
Dim sBook_s As Workbook
Dim wbPath_t As String
Dim wbPath_s As String
Dim lRow2 As Long


wbPath_t = "\\file086\Worksheet Test.xlsb"
wbPath_s = "\\file080\SYNC_FTD2.csv"

Set sBook_t = Workbooks.Open(wbPath_t)
Set sBook_s = Workbooks.Open(wbPath_s)
    
'Find last row in paste workbook
lRow2 = sBook_t.Sheets("Data Dump").Range("B" & sBook_t.Sheets("Data Dump").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'copy and paste
sBook_s.Sheets("LocationAllocation").Range("A2:M300").Copy
sBook_t.Sheets("Data Dump").Range("B" & lRow2).Paste                 <--- RUN TIME ERROR 438
   
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Set sBook_s = Nothing
Set sBook_t = Nothing
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Indeed, `Range` [does not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)#methods) have a method called `Paste`.

Comment: Can you suggest what method would be appropriate to paste?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have your 2 worksheets misidentified. With the copy command you just want to identify the paste range on the same line. Correcting these 2 lines seems to work.

```
'Find last row in paste workbook
lRow2 = sBook_s.Sheets("Data Dump").Range("B" & sBook_s.Sheets("DataDump").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'copy and paste
sBook_t.Sheets("LocationAllocation").Range("A2:M300").Copy sBook_s.Sheets("Data Dump").Range("B" & lRow2)
```